# How to apply CSS to anchor with active class only (parent only) and not include children?

Tags: css

**Resolved Thanks!**

I need to apply css to the current active menu (PARENT LIST li item), this is my code:

```
#supermenu li.current-menu-item a, #supermenu li.current-menu-item a:hover {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #ea6ea0;
      border-right: 1px solid #ea6ea0;
      box-shadow:inset 0 -1px 2px #bf1358;
}
```

Overriding the links for children looking like a long messy process, any clean way to exclude the children links?

but the css get applied to the children LINKS / anchors because it is used in conjuction with dropdown menu, how can I stop the children links from having the same css?

Thanks

Comment: Huh? Are you nesting anchors inside anchors?

Comment: why dont you add another class to the parent

Comment: It is the parent li which has the active class, not the anchor. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, please try this:

```
#supermenu li.current-menu-item > a,
#supermenu li.current-menu-item > a:hover {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #ea6ea0;
      border-right: 1px solid #ea6ea0;
      box-shadow:inset 0 -1px 2px #bf1358;
}
```

You can take a look at this [article](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) to understand the `>` *[child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators)*.

Note that it doesn't work for **IE6** or lower.

Comment: I edited the answer to add some useful links for you to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `>` operator, that will only match the direct descendants.

This should work:

```
#supermenu li.current-menu-item > a, 
#supermenu li.current-menu-item > a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ea6ea0;
  border-right: 1px solid #ea6ea0;
  box-shadow:inset 0 -1px 2px #bf1358;
}
```

Note that IE7 and older doesn't support it.

Comment: And what is alternative for IE7 and older?

Comment: IE7 does support it, IE6 and lower doesn't, however... There is no pure CSS alternative for this, so you'd need JS for IE6 (if you do need to support it). Or - add additional classes to elements that you need to style differently.